# Error while building Unity3D Android Game := Plugins colliding with each other

Tags: android, plugins, unity-game-engine, build, android-manifest

when I build the game in Unity3D , 
it makes error :"plugins colliding with each other"

I am using Facebook SDK and Playfab.com SDK

> Found plugins with same names and architectures,
>   Assets/Plugins/Android/libs/android-support-v4.jar (ARMv7) and
>   Assets/Plugins/Android/android-support-v4.jar (ARMv7). Assign
>   different architectures or delete the duplicate.
>   UnityEditor.AndroidPluginImporterExtension:CheckFileCollisions(String)
>   UnityEditorInternal.PluginsHelper:CheckFileCollisions(BuildTarget) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Plugins/PluginsHelper.cs:25)
>   UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

I tried to remove this file : Assets/Plugins/Android/libs/android-support-v4.jar
but I got another error

> Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:3, D:\work\Apes
>   Shelter\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-sdk-4.7.0\AndroidManifest.xml:3]
>   Main manifest has  but library
>   uses minSdkVersion='15'

any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check **Minimum API Level** in **'Build Settings/Other Settings'**.
[Here is](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/101531/unity-main-manifest-has-uses-sdk-androidminsdkversion-9-but-library-uses) someone with the same problem. Just set Minimum API Level to 15.

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM WHEN BUILDING ANDROID AND FACEBOOK SDK

this happens because 2 things:

1.Facebook SDK include files already contained in Assest/plugins/android, and

2. AndroidManifest.xml has to be updated.

so I did this:

1. Open AndroidManifest.xml (Assest/plugins/android/AndroidManifest.xml) with Xcode or Text edit and change line to this:

   uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="23"

   READ the error, it will tell you the values needed.
2. Assest/plugins/android/libs (NOT FacebookSDK/plugins/android/libs )  select All files, and in inspector deselect "android". (some people suggest to delete them, but i just deselect them so when the project builds they won't be included).
3. in finder look for .jar files duplicates and delete the ones that are in plugins/android Not the ones in Facebook

this was my case, maybe your is different, what I did was to look for duplicate files in Facebook SDK and Assest/plugins/android!